# Verify sms text message by app before it displayed to user

Tags: java, android, sms

Do we have an option in Android to verify sms text words
before displaying it on the screen to user?
Can I block this text message with specific text, controlling it in code?

Any ideas or tutorials about this thing?

Comment: is it what you are looking for is when an sms is received is should be checked in your app and if matches a particular text it should not reach the inbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use BroadcastReceiver to get the incoming sms

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Log.i(TAG, "Intent received: " + intent.getAction());

    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            if (messages.length > -1) {                 

                  String str=messages[0].getMessageBody();

                  if(check for the text in the string str)
                  {                      
                      abortBroadcast();//stops msg from reaching inbox                   
                  } 

              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

add these permissions to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Add receiver to your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: It's strange,I set breakpoint after `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {`
Sending sms to myself, but no logs and the debugger does not stops

Comment: is your message delivered to your inbox?

Comment: of course, immediately the clais message box appears and other apps (viber...)

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast receiver as below

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras == null)
    return;



    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage
                .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
        String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
        Log.e("message: ", body);
        Log.e("Number", sender);

        Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").putExtra(
                "get_msg", sender + ":" + body);

        context.sendBroadcast(in);

if (body.equals("your text") {  
  this.abortBroadcast();            
}       
    }



}

}
```

In manifest register your receiver as

```
   <receiver
        android:name="yourpackagename.SMSReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This will do the trick. Hope this helps. :)