# check automatically for new message android

Tags: java, android, notifications, chat, message

I am trying to create a simple android messaging app. So basically let us assume that user A sends a message to user B. I would like that user B receives a notification when the message is received. I know how to create the notification and all. But basically I would like to know how the user B constantly checks if a new message has been received even when he is out of the app, and then that would trigger the notification and subsequent actions.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to setup an unbound background service.
With this you can constantly make pull-requests to your server or get push-notifications from your server and display notifications.
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it might be fitting my needs, but it does not keep running the requests when the application is closed, but still I would like to. As whatsapp does in some sense.

Comment: There are different methods to keep the service alive, e.g. onStartCommand return START_STICKY, AlarmManager to restart the Service, ...
But you cannot keep a service alive infinitely (without a permanent notification).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Event Bus lib](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for this purpose. When new message will be received it will create and event and then you can receive that event event and do other operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about text messages then you will have to create a BroadcastReceiver 
    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
You can see my answer here for SMS Receiver
[Verify sms text message by app before it displayed to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691203/verify-sms-text-message-by-app-before-it-displayed-to-user/16692125#16692125)
Don't forget to give permissions in your app's manifest.

Hope it helps.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver!!! It will recieve incoming text message not message form private server. How to implement it for private server? Can you explain?